# Kohana ORM module not working

Tags: orm, kohana

I'm learning Kohana at the mo and encountering the following error when trying to extend a model to use ORM.

Declaration of Model_Message::create() should be compatible with that of Kohana_ORM::create()

I've enabled the orm in my bootstrap along with the database.  The error highlights the following line on the error dump.

class Model_Message extends ORM {

And here is the model code I'm using and failing with...

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access');
/**
 * Message modal
 * Handles CRUD for user messages
 */

class Model_Message extends ORM {

    /**
     * Adds a new message for a user
     *
     * @param       int         user_id
     * @param       string  user's message
     * @return  self
     */
    public function create($user_id, $content)
    {
        $this->clear();
        $this->user_id = $user_id;
        $this->content = $content;
        $this->date_published = time();
        return $this->save();
    }

}
```

I've been going through the api documentation and everything is saying that this way of implementing the orm from the model is the correct way to do so.  Any pointers would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rename your method (create_message for example) or make it compatible with ORM (because it has the it's own create method which you try to override).